# how to change link captions in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to change link caption 
my plunker is given here

```
            <ul class="bk_crs_rslt">
                <li ng-repeat="c in courses">
                    <h4> {{c.CourseName }}<img src="image/bk_ad_btn.jpg" /> </h4>
                    <p><span style="color:#337ab7;">{{c.CollegeName}}</span><br>{{c.CountryName}}</p>
                    <p>
                        <a href="#" ng-click="c.show = !c.show" ng-show="!c.show"><img class="info_arw" src="image/bk_down_arw.png" />More Information</a>
                    </p>
                    <div>
                        <p ng-show="!c.show">
                            <b>Tution Fee</b>     :  {{c.Fee}}<br>
                            <b>Level</b>          :  {{c.LevelName}}<br>
                            <b>Detail </b>        :  {{c.Detail}} <br>
                            <b>Duration </b>      :   {{c.Duration}}<br>
                            <b>Subject </b>       :  {{c.Subjec}}t<br>
                            <b>IELTS Score </b>   :  {{c.Score}}<br />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <a href="#" ng-click="c.show = !c.show"><img class="info_arw" src="image/bk_up_arw.png" />Hide Information</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </li>

            </ul>      


</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/lsIypaBviXNvEi7Pwok4?p=preview

iwant only one link. if i press 'more information' detail show then change the link caption as' hide information'and viceversa

please helpme

Answer (score 0):

**Already all hidden :**

Change your code like this : https://plnkr.co/edit/tpz7RLxOdy8aUe2My63y?p=preview

```
<p ng-init="c.show = true" ng-show="c.show">
      <a href="#" ng-click="c.show = !c.show"><img class="info_arw" src="image/bk_down_arw.png" />More Information</a>
</p>
<div ng-show="!c.show">
  <p>
    <b>Tution Fee</b> : {{c.Fee}}<br/>
    <b>Level</b> : {{c.LevelName}}<br/>
    <b>Detail </b> : {{c.Detail}}<br/>
    <b>Duration </b> : {{c.Duration}}<br/>
    <b>Subject </b> : {{c.Subject}}<br/>
    <b>IELTS Score </b> : {{c.Score}}<br />
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="#" ng-click="c.show = !c.show"><img class="info_arw" src="image/bk_up_arw.png" />Hide Information</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

---

**Already all opened :**

Or you can do something like this : https://plnkr.co/edit/JVpuFqA9b05w5kjAnZGN?p=preview

```
<p>
  <a href="#" ng-click="c.show = !c.show" ng-show="c.show">
    <img class="info_arw" src="image/bk_down_arw.png" />More Information</a>
</p>
<div ng-show="!c.show">
  <p>
    <b>Tution Fee</b> : {{c.Fee}}<br/>
    <b>Level</b> : {{c.LevelName}}<br/>
    <b>Detail </b> : {{c.Detail}}<br/>
    <b>Duration </b> : {{c.Duration}}<br/>
    <b>Subject </b> : {{c.Subject}}<br/>
    <b>IELTS Score </b> : {{c.Score}}<br />
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="#" ng-click="c.show = !c.show"><img class="info_arw" src="image/bk_up_arw.png" />Hide Information</a>
  </p>
</div>
```